# Portably use special characters in parameter expansion, with or without double quotes

Tags: shell, posix

In all of the following shells:

- bash
- ksh
- zsh
- dash

and without a way to influence either the choice of shell or of shell
settings, my goal is to use the default string value `(y!)` whenever
the variable named `x` is unset or null. I.e., I want the shell to
perform parameter expansion producing `(y!)` where `y` stands for some
text not involving any special characters. So, **naively**,

```
${x:-(y!)}
```

There may be double quotes. A number of differences become apparent, then, among the shells
interpreting this or a variation. In an attempt to
approach portability, I tried variants adding zero to three `\`s. I then also
tried the effects of spaces, but I'll exclude that for now.

```
${x:-(y!)}, ... , ${x:-\(y\!\)}
```

One of the differences shown by the shells would, I guess, be related to a shell's
overloading of `!` for history events. (Try `!echo` in zsh.)
Other differences remain when a variant occurs between double quotes.
A solution would ideally work between double quotes, as I cannot really
expect a scheme not to be used in this context.

E.g., given comand `echo "$0: ${x:-\(y\!\)}"`, i.e., with all of `(`, `!`,
and `)` preceded by `\`, the shells respond:

```
-bash: \(y\!\)
ksh: \(y\!\)
zsh: \(y!\)
dash: \(y\!\)
```

So, the Z Shell begs to differ.  It turns out that the following seems
to be working alike in bash, ksh, zsh, and dash:

```
$ echo "${x:-$(echo \(y\!\))}"
(y!)
```

But involving another command substitution (`echo`, even if
built-in(?)) seems overkill. Is there a better way? At all? Am I
missing something?

(Zsh seems to use `!{...}`, so not `\`, to “insulate a history
reference from adjacent characters (if necessary)” (zshexpn(1)). Maybe that explains why it responds differently?)

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas I think you are the right person to answer this question - and will be a chance for us to learn

Comment: How about `y='(y!)'; echo "${x:-"$y"}"`? POSIX conformant shells should expand that to `(y!)` if `x` is unset or null.

Comment: @BenjaminW., the idea would be quite o.K. for my own scripts (whenever there isn't anything else to expand, so that `'`ing suffices as suggested). Some discipline when choosing names for `y` might even result in an improvement. I'm not sure, though, whether I can offer it as a generally applicable procedure of using expansion and double quotes, but it might work with the added persuasion of some remarks involving “practical” and “technical reasons”.

Comment: History expansion does not apply to scripts. It's only enabled for interactive sessions. `echo "${x:-(y!)}"` should be fine.

Comment: Maybe it is safe to assume that `history` and `histexpand` have their default values in bash scripts, say. It does look, though, as if I should be using a two-step mechanism that works without making any such assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Using the octal code for the `!` char seems to work:

```
/bin/echo -e "'${x:-(y\0041)}'"
```

The builtin `echo` commands for the various shells are inconsistent, (two require the `-e` switch, but `dash` doesn't understand it), so `/bin/echo` is more reliable.  Test the four shells:

```
unset x
for f in dash bash zsh ksh ; do 
     echo -en "$f:\t"
     $f -c "/bin/echo -e \"'\${x:-(y\0041)}'\""
done
```

Output:

```
dash:   '(y!)'
bash:   '(y!)'
zsh:    '(y!)'
ksh:    '(y!)'
```

Comment: `echo` commands are inconsistent indeed. E.g., I see `bash: -e '(y\0041)'` on a Mac. But this is another hint at moving the expansion outwards.